# How do we use "which" with a preposition in front of it to create a relative clause that you want to further describe the quality you have mentioned

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage, relative-clauses, possessive-of-which

Tom has a good mixture of characters, among which I am the most amazed by his patience and focus to solve puzzles.

Is it correction to use "among which" in the sentence above?

Comment: I don't have any substantive arguments about the correctness or otherwise of the sentence. Nevertheless, it sounds a bit suspect to me, because I would expect the relative clause to have one of the characteristics as its subject, not "I". This would result in a reworking as follows: "_Tom has a good mixture of characteristics, of which the one that I am the most amazed by is his patience and focus to solve puzzles._"

Comment: ... Yes; OP has 'I' among the set of good _character **traits**_.